# Suppose You have an array that contains some strings as name of something. Now,you have to find one string that contains odd letter by java script

Tags: arrays, function, loops

const array=['abul','babu','rony','babul','suny'];
function{`enter code here`}

Comment: This could use some clarification. What do you mean by "contains odd letter?"   
Do you mean you want to find the word with an odd number of letters?

Comment: Yes brother. Thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to use the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) operator to determine if the string length is odd and [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the value in the list

> The remainder operator (%) returns the remainder left over when one operand is divided by a second operand.

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.

```
const names = ['abul','babu','rony','babul','suny']

// function that takes a string and returns true if the string has odd length
// determines whether a string's length is odd using modulo operator and checking remainder
const hasOddLength = str => str.length % 2 !== 0

// uses hasOddLength as callback for find()
const findStringWithOddLength = (list) => (
  list.find(str => hasOddLength(str))
)

console.log(findStringWithOddLength(names)) // "babul"
```

Note: if there are multiple names with an odd length, `find()` will only return the first one.